# Authorise Windows Users without any authentication ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I've just built my 1st asp.net mvc application and deployed it in remote IIS.I don't want to have any login option for the application but would like to authorise users based on their user-ids(eg:domainname\username) without any login.I tried using authorize attribute but it is working only when windows authentication type is enabled and is asking for windows login(windows login popsup) whenever the application is opened and doesnot work even after giving the login credentials.
Can someone please assist me on how to implement it without any authentication?
Please let me know if you would like me to add any other details.

Comment: [How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx): "If you are using the Visual Studio Development server, you are not prompted for credentials and you see only a blank page." - According to the docs, it only works with IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: Without windows authentication enabled browser will not pass windows credentials to server. Reason you may be getting login popup when application from remote server is accessed is either remote server is in different domain than your client machine or your browser setting "Enable Windows Integrated Authentication" is not enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much @NightOwl888.That was a good demo.Tried it but  did not test with the other users yet.But previously I almost did in the same way and was working fine only for me.Though the users are authorized , they are always asked for login and when they try to login it shows the page without rendering any CSS or JS.

Comment: Thank you so much @PankajKapare..May I know if there is any way that we can bypass or eliminate the login popup without changing any setting in the browser.?